# Is it possible to integrate Vaadin with Rails??? If so, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vaadin, integrate

As i see Vaadin is a Java based UI framework. But it has some really nice set of widgets and a very good layout engine. Is it possible to integrate Rails and Vaadin? JSON perhaps??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like that'd take a lot of work creating an interface between them which will likely only slow things down. By the time you had everything working the way you wanted you could've finished what you wanted in Rails or Vaadin separately.

If you did make an interface, JSON is the way to go. Lightweight and almost everything supports it with little overhead.

Comment: I agree.. i am looking for a really good UI framework which integrates well with rails... is there any alternative to javascript based frameworks?? other than the usual ones (jquery, prototype, sproutcore etc.)

Comment: @Shripad - if you are looking for rich ui components, you may consider jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/) or ExtJS (http://www.sencha.com/products/js/).

Answer (score 1):

> is there any alternative to javascript based frameworks?? other than the usual ones (jquery, prototype, sproutcore

Just pointing out, that all rich UI frameworks that run in the browser are JavaScript in the end (not including any plugins like Flash), even Vaadin, which is built on top of GWT on the client side.

I guess you'll have to consider integrating with the Rails backend either on the server side (e.g. with a Vaadin Java servlet) or on the client side with a custom data exchange over HTTP (using JSON) and using some client side framework like GWT, SproutCore, Cappuccino etc.